# javascript function does not wait ajax execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have i javascript function does not wait ajax execution quit immediately with no wating execution what is the problem seriously my code below:

i made an alert at the end: precisely to stop  it.
when the alert show i wait a little bit the result from the server and the return is result not null from the server.
when i disable the alert the result is undefined.

```
function getAllBathyms() {

    var idbar = $("#list_barrages").val();
    var idorg = $("#list_organisations").val();

    if (idbar == "" || idbar == "--" || idbar == "NaN") {
        alert("veuillez séléctionner un barrage SVP:");
    }
    if (idorg == "" || idorg == "--" || idorg == "NaN") {
        alert("veuillez séléctionner un barrage une agence SVP:");

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/CourbesNiveaux/getAllBathyms")',
        data: { 'idbar': idbar, 'idorg': idorg },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok ajax');
            console.log('ok ajax');
            bathyms = data;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('server problems');
        }
    });
    return bathyms;
}
```

Comment: *"i have i javascript function does not wait ajax execution"* That's normal, because Ajax stands for *"**Asynchronous** JavaScript And XML"*. They included the term *asynchronous* for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Add async:false in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async:false, 
        url: '@Url.Content("~/CourbesNiveaux/getAllBathyms")',
```

Comment: @ezzaam: Make sure to read the accepted answer in the linked question, to understand why making the call synchronous is generally a bad idea.

Comment: yes i konw thanks a lot but in this case no way

Answer (score 0):

because ajax is asynchronous. it will not wait for the success event to happen. If you want to do so, put

```
async:false
```

in your code

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** You can always set your AJAX call to be synchronius, but be ready that the whole page stucks while waiting for response. just add parameter async: false to your set of parameters. *note that is a really really big no-no and bad practice!*

**Option 2:** Provide callbacks or put your future code inside success handler

**Option 3:** You can use defer/promise described here http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics